# How to get this chart to show numbers instead of squares

Tags: string, numbers, tableau-api, texttable

I transferred the file from Excel into my Tableau sheet and created two new variables.  One is a parameter based on the Sales variable.  I set the value at 10,000.  Then I created a calculated variable called "Sales Spotlight" that states:

```
IF(SUM([Sales])) >= [Sales Parameter] THEN "Good" ELSE "Bad" END
```

This is what the screen looks like:

[image]

The result is correct except the values in the table are string values instead of number values.  I can't figure out how to change the data in the table to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you want to display Sales as a number in your chart?

In theory, you should be able to do this by changing Mark type from "Automatic" to "Number" (or "Text"?).

Failing that, try dragging Sales from the far-left side on to your viz under Rows, and again explicitly set the Mark type.

Proviso: it's been a while since I've used Tableau and I don't have it available so cannot verify the answer above but it should work.